# How can I get a single item from the array and display it as an object? and not as an array Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have a collection from which I need specific obj e.g. `notes.blok2` and `notes.curse5` as an object, not as an array

```
{
  "year":2020,
  "grade":4,
  "seccion":"A",
    "id": 100,
  "name": "pedro",
  "notes":[{"curse":5, 
          "block":1, 
          "score":{ "a1": 5,"a2": 10, "a3": 15} 
          },{"curse":5, 
          "block":2, 
          "score":{ "b1": 10,"b2": 20, "b3": 30} 
          }
   ]
}
```

**My query**

```
notas.find({
"$and":[{"grade":1},{"seccion":"A"},{"year":2020}]},
{"projection":{ "grade":1, "seccion":1,"name":1,"id":1,
"notes":{"$elemMatch":{"block":2,"curse":5}},"notes.score":1} })
```

It works but returns notes like array

```
{
  "_id": "55",
  "id": 100,
  "grade": 5,
  "name": "pedro",
  "seccion": "A",
  "notes": [
    {"score": { "b1": 10,"b2": 20, "b3": 30} }
  ]
}
```

But I NEED LIKE THIS: `score` at the same level as others and if doesn't exist show empty `"score":{}`

```
{
  "year":2020,
  "grade":5,
  "seccion":"A",
    "id": 100,
  "name": "pedro",
  "score":{ "b1": 10,"b2": 20, "b3": 30} 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/XlJqR2DYW1X

You can use aggregation query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { // filter
      "grade": 1,
      "seccion": "A",
      "year": 2020,
      "notes": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "block": 2,
          "curse": 5
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$notes" },  //break into individual documents
  {
    $match: { // match query on individual note
      "notes.block": 2,
      "notes.curse": 5
    }
  },
  {
    $project: { // projection
      "grade": 1,
      "seccion": 1,
      "name": 1,
      "id": 1,
      "score": "$notes.score"
    }
  }
])
```

---

Update

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/mq5Kue3UG42

Use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "grade": 1,
      "seccion": "A",
      "year": 2020
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "score": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$notes",
          "as": "note",
          "cond": {
            $and: [
              {
                $eq: [ "$$note.block",3]
              },
              {
                $eq: [ "$$note.curse", 5 ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      // projection
      "grade": 1,
      "seccion": 1,
      "name": 1,
      "id": 1,
      "score": {
        "$first": "$score.score"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

---

If you want empty object for score when match not found you can do -

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/dumax58kgrc

```
  {
    $set: {
      score: {
        $cond: [
          { $size: "$score" }, // check array length
          { $first: "$score" }, // true - take 1st
          { score: {} } // false - set empty object
        ]
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: i have a problem bcase, I need the name and id even if I don't have score

Comment: Updated @Carlos please check.

Comment: Please help one more, if I want to update one element from score, who can I do it?

Comment: Please help me, you can teach me who can i update single score? please

Comment: @Carlos Sure, can you give me link to the question ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67425380/update-specific-element-from-nested-document-array-mongodb-where-has-two-matches

Comment: please here link

Comment: @Carlos Done, hope it helps :)