# update specific element from nested document array mongodb where has two matches

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, laravel-mongodb

I need to update or create if not exist, specific obj,set score.b1 =50  and total=100 where object match curse=5 block=2

```
{ "_id":"sad445"
  "year":2020,
  "grade":4,
  "seccion":"A",
    "id": 100,
  "name": "pedro",
  "notes":[{"curse":5, 
          "block":1, 
          "score":{ "a1": 5,"a2": 10, "a3": 15},
          "total" : 50
          },{
          "curse":5, 
          "block":2, 
          "score":{ "b1": 10,"b2": 20, "b3": 30},
          "total" : 20
          }
   ]
}
```

I can update all obj but I need to update or create specific elem from the score and not all. and/or  create objs   "notes":[**{curse, block and score}**]  if notes is empty notes:[]

```
notas.UpdateMany(
{"$and":[{"_id":"sad445"},{"notes":{"$elemMatch":{"curse":5,"block":3}}}]},

{"$set":{"updated_at":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1620322881360"}},

"notes.$.score":{"vvkzo":15,"i2z4i":2,"i2z4i|pm":5},
"notes.$.total":100}},

{"multiple":false})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/VaE28ujeOPx

Use [$ (update)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)

> The positional $ operator identifies an element in an array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array.

> the positional $ operator acts as a placeholder for the **first** element that matches the query document, and

> the array field must appear as part of the query document.

```
db.collection.update({
  "notes": {
    "$elemMatch": { "block": 2, "curse": 5 }
  }
},
{
  $set: { "notes.$.score.b4": 40 }
})
```

---

Read [upsert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#std-label-update-upsert): true

> Optional. When true, update() either:
>
> Creates a new document if no documents match the query. For more
> details see upsert behavior. Updates a single document that matches
> the query. If both upsert and multi are true and no documents match
> the query, the update operation inserts only a single document.
>
> To avoid multiple upserts, ensure that the query field(s) are uniquely
> indexed. See Upsert with Unique Index for an example.
>
> Defaults to false, which does not insert a new document when no match
> is found.

---

#### Update

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/iQQDyjG2a_B

Use [$function](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/)

```
db.collection.update(
    { "_id": "sad445" },
    [
      {
        $set: {
          notes: {
            $function: {
              body: function(notes) {
                        var record = { curse:5, block:2, score:{ b4:40 } };
                        if(!notes || !notes.length) { return [record]; } // create new record and return in case of no notes
                        var updated = false;
                        for (var i=0; i < notes.length; i++) {
                            if (notes[i].block == 2 && notes[i].curse == 5) { // check condition for update
                                updated = true;
                                notes[i].score.b4=40; break; // update here
                            }
                        }
                        if (!updated) notes.push(record); // if no update push the record in notes array
                        return notes;
                    },
              args: [
                "$notes"
              ],
              lang: "js"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
)
```

Comment: yes!!  works but My problem is when the `"notes": []` is empty, in this case, I need to create obj {"curse": 5, "block": 2, "notes":{"b4": 100} } please help me how can I do it.

Comment: @Carlos Which version of mongodb are you using ?

Comment: mongodb v 4.4.5

Comment: thanks so much!!! where are you from? and where are you studied?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `upsert: true`.

> Creates a new document if no documents match the query. Updates a single document that matches
> the query.

```
notas.UpdateMany(
{"$and":[{"_id":"sad445"},{"notes":{"$elemMatch":{"curse":5,"block":3}}}]},

{"$set":{"updated_at":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1620322881360"}},

"notes.$.score":{"vvkzo":15,"i2z4i":2,"i2z4i|pm":5},
"notes.$.total":100}},

{"multiple":false, "upsert":true})
```